# Remove all related mail files within Windows 7

Tags: windows, email

I have windows 8 machine and I will give my pc to company owns it. The thing is I dont want anybody able to see my "old" e-mails. I removed from these e-mails in Outlook but:
when I click windows icon left bottom and type somethings related with a deleted mail, it appears in there..(when I try to open it it propt a msg that it is deleted and ask me to remove shortcut too.)

So I want to delete all these fiels completely and not able to see anything about them it musnt be able to search by somehow.. 
I dont want anything exist about that files in pc

Edited:
I click and view properties of that file appears on windows start bar it located in

> "C:/Users/10023213"

so I would think to delete this directory but there is also "AppData" file in it which used by other stuff.. I couldnt figure it out how to remove things about only e mails once for all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Close Outlook.

Go into Control Panel, and in the search box at the top choose *Mail* (or *Mail (32-bit)*).

Click the *Data Files...* button, highlight your name in the list, and then click the *Open File Location* button, which will open Windows Explorer. Leave Explorer open, but close the Data Files dialog.

Click the *Show Profiles...* button, where you should see *Outlook* or your profile name. Select it and click *Remove*.

Close the Mail control panel dialog. Go back to the Explorer window you left open before, and delete the *youremail@yourmailhost.ost* file, which is all of your email content (inbox, sent, etc.). You may want to delete all of the other files and folders in this folder, as they're all of your Outlook related info (address book, etc.).